# Why did this character in Prometheus kill without apparent reason?

Tags: plot-explanation, prometheus

At the end of Prometheus, why did the Engineer kill the humans? What is that thing that killed the Engineer?

Comment: Edited the title to clarify that 'Alien' means 'Engineer' not the creatures from the Alien franchise.  ALso, please keep spoilers from the title of a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Alien you are saying is actually an "Engineer" and they developed the so called "parasite plague" to end the planet earth (which they created in the first place).

If you remember the alien or parasite plague agent that killed "engineer" was forcefully taken out by Elizabeth (Eli) from her stomach in the med pod. She actually froze it using decontamination gas of the med pod but it survived and tried to come out of that room at the end and the "engineer" was accidentally present there at the same time. The alien killed the engineer and supposedly impregnated him and that's why you see a new alien born at the end of the movie.

Check [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/board/nest/204361312) post which gives an insight into the whole plot.

Answer (score 2):

So I have been doing a lot of thinking and I realized that Elizabeth wanted to kill the alien inside of her as soon as she found out about it. Maybe the engineers made us by mistake just as Elizabeth and Holloway did. Maybe they thought they would create something else!